# Database Authentication with/after Shibboleth authentication

Tags: node.js, postgresql, shibboleth

thanks for trying to help me.

My setup:

1 Apache Webserver with shibboleth Service Provider 
2. Node Js Server / api
3. Angular Frontend 
4. PostgreSQL database

What I am doing and what I want to do:

I go to my web apps URL 
https://myurl.com
Apache sends me to a shibboleth authentication side and after a successful login it will send me to the start page of my app. -> works

Now I want to login the user directly to my app if there is the same username in the database as the one I got from shibboleth. -> not working 
(I don’t now how to manage this without saving the DB pw for the user somewhere on the server)

At the moment the user needs to login with his DB credentials in my Frontend. After pressing the login button on my angular app there is a post request sent to my node api. 
A database object will be created with pg promise library and now the user is able to get data from the database and will be logged in.

I can’t get a password from the shibboleth authentication server. I only get the user name.

I will try to add some code tonight.

What is the best way to login the user to the database after shibboleth authentication?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't need the password from the identity provider - you definitely trust the provider when it comes to authentication. You only need the user name. Then, you need to find the point in your node.js code when the shibboleth token is extracted and validated. This is where you need to **add some custom code**. This code would search your postgress database, find an existing user of the same name or **create a new user** and then establish a local session, in the very same way you establish it when your users log in a regular way.

Comment: @WiktorZychla is correct. You are trusting the Identity Provider in the SAML exchange, and Shib SP won't let the user access secured resources without authentication from the IdP, so you don't need the user's password. You just need to create a session (however you do so in your app).